# testing locally managed indentity with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-managed-identity

I was trying to setup code using python to test the azure managed identity services and with C# I can able to test the code locally. Is there any way to test the python code locally?

Enabled managed identity in azure appservice
Added the application user(appservice) in azure SQL server and gave permissions.

this is my sample python code to connect to azure sql with managed identity

```
conn = db.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                  'Server=testdb.database.windows.net;'
                  'Database=studentdb;'
                  'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;'
                  )

        query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM STUDENT', conn)

        frame = pd.DataFrame(query)
        return func.HttpResponse(frame.to_json(orient="index"), status_code=200)
```

Can anyone help me to test this code locally? as i do not have permissions on azure to deploy this code and test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Moto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-lambda-local) library which allow you to test services. You can run the Lambda functions in the same way you would run python script.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
event = []
context = []
lambda_handler(event, context)
```

If you are in a virtual environment then this will ensure that all the required dependencies installed properly for the lambda function with correct python function.

Answer (score 0):

If you check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-integrate-azure-managed-service-identity?tabs=core5x#:%7E:text=Managed%20Identity%20cannot%20be%20used%20to%20authenticate%20locally-running%20applications.%20Your%20application%20must%20be%20deployed%20to%20an%20Azure%20service%20that%20supports%20Managed%20Identity.) from Microsoft, then you will find that -

> **Managed Identity cannot be used to authenticate locally-running applications. Your application must be deployed to an Azure service that supports Managed Identity.**

It's important to understand that Managed Identity feature in Azure is ONLY relevant when, in this case, the App Service is deployed.

**As an alternative you can use `DefaultAzureCredential()` from the `Azure.Identity` library which is compatible both when running locally and for the deployed web app.** You can read more about how `Azure.Identity` works from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate?tabs=cmd).

Most of the time we use Azure MSI to connect Azure SQL in Azure function with python. We can can use Azure MSI to get Azure AD access token then you can use the token to connect Azure SQL.

Once you enabled system assigned identity on your Azure Web App and gave SQL permissions, you can get access to the database directly from python as shown in the snippet below.

```py
import pyodbc  
from logzero import loggerwith pyodbc.connect(  
            "Driver=" + driver + ";Server=" + server + ";PORT=1433;Database=" + database  
             + ";Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi",  
) as conn:  
        logger.info("Successful connection to database")
with conn.cursor() as cursor:  
        cursor.execute(“select @@version")).fetchall()
```

Following are the parameters used above:

- **Driver**: We should use : “{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}”
- **Server**: The sql server on which is your database
- **Database**: The name of your database
- **Authentication**: To specify the connection method “ActiveDirectoryMsi”

Check the [SQL database access with managed identity from Azure Web App](https://hedihargam.medium.com/python-sql-database-access-with-managed-identity-from-azure-web-app-functions-14566e5a0f1a) document  and [Configure your local Python dev environment for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-local-development-environment?tabs=cmd) document for more information.